# linux driver check process is alive

Tags: c++, linux

I have a simple linux module for work with interruptions.
I send the signal to the my process pid every time when have interraption.
But how i can check the PID is alive or not?
I tryed use find_task_by_vpid in a interraption handler function.
But after that some times kernel is crashed.

```
NIP [c003ba9c] find_task_by_vpid+0x2c/0x4cfind_task_by_vpi d[ 782.391934] Unable to handle kernel
```

So now i get find_task_by_vpid only one time.
And it's work ok.
But when i kill my process like a "kill -9" my core is crashed.
Please, help me

Answer (score 0):

PIDs are not a reliable to identify a process. PIDs may be reused, so if your destination process terminates (for whatever reason), its PID may be reused, without your kernel module getting notice for that. So:

**Don't use PIDs for communicating with processes!¹**

Use file operations for communication between kernel and user space. Either in the form of a character or block device in `/dev` or as an entry in procfs `/proc` or in the sysfs `/sys`.

Have the user space process open the file; your kernel module offers a set of *file operation* handler functions (fops). When the process terminates, all file descriptors are closed, and the *close* fop of your kernel module gets called.

---

1: As a matter of fact, PIDs are unreliable everywhere and their use for anything should be avoided. The only sitation in which a PID is somewhat reliable is inside the parent process, that forked off that PID, since `wait`-s will prevent the process to completely vanish until the parent dealt with its demise. But anyone else on the system has no information about that.

Comment: Yes. Use character look like a good way.
But I can’t understand how using these operations to inform the process about the event?

Comment: @Evlampii: Implement the `poll` fop for the character device and have the userspace process use one of the event notification APIs (`select`, `epoll`, `eventfd`).